# How do I put a variable in an src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, attributes

Ok so I have this problem .  I want to put the `myPath` variable into my `src` attribute of my image.

```
var myPath = img/image.png;
//it's actually set by another function

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='myPath'>";
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How do I do it ?

(I'm really new with js)

Comment: Does the image element already exists in the `.myDiv` or are you trying to **add** a new image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With javascript:

- you can add and remove **elements** to and from **documents**; and
- you can add and remove **attributes** to and from **elements**

So if in your markup you have something like:

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

You can add an `img` element as a child of the `div` element, like so:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div'); // grabs #my-div
var myPath = 'img/image.png'; // initialises string variable myPath
var myImg = document.createElement('img'); // creates a new img element


myImg.setAttribute('src', myPath); // adds a src attribute (with the value myPath) to myImg
myDiv.appendChild(myImg); // adds a child element (myImg) to myDiv
```

Answer (score 2):

`myPath` already contains a string, in your code you are not using the variable myPath rather myPath is just a part of string literal, you need to use string concatenation, you can do something like this:

```
var myPath = "img/image.png";
//it's actually set by another function

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myPath + "'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concat it as an string

```
var myPath = "img/image.png";
//it's actually set by another function

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='"+myPath"'>";
```